# SQL stored procedure return value to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to get value from stored procedure for registration, but I can't pass the value from the stored procedure to the server

Stored procedure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tylEi.png)

Server:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxDiz.png)

Comment: Please, post the code **as TEXT** (and properly format it by clicking the `{ ..}` button) - not as a screenshot !

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Result bit Output` parameter from your Proc.. just declare after `AS` if you need it

Comment: can you send an example?

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure it is unnecessary to return `@Result` as it is declared as an output parameter.

Take a look at [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-retrieve-output-e85526ba) article about using output parameters with EF.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What behavior are you seeing. What have you changed in your code?

Comment: it's also not return any value and don't do nothing